# Linking .h file with .cpp file

Tags: c++

I have a very simple test_planner.h file:

```
class TestPlanner
{
public:
 double GetTheSum(double n1, double n2) {return n1 + n2;}
};
```

which works well when I call the function "GetTheSum" from GoogleTest.

Now I want to split this file to a .h and a .cpp file.

test_planner.h:

```
class TestPlanner
{
public:
 double GetTheSum(double n1, double n2);
};
```

and a respective test_planner.cpp file in the same folder:

```
#include "test_planner.h"

double TestPlanner::GetTheSum(double n1, double n2)
{
  return n1 + n2;
}
```

If I run the same GoogleTest now I receive an error message to an "undefined reference to `TestPlanner::GetTheSum(double, double)'". I think my mistake must be in the linking of the two files but I cannot figure out what I did wrong. The problem is even to simple to find similar problems in the Q&A search.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? You need to link the *.cpp file.

Comment: The problem isn't the header file or or its "linking", it's that you don't build with the *source* file `test_planner.cpp`.

Comment: specifically [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/4342498) answer.

Comment: Do you have a header guard in your .h file?

Comment: I use gcc compiler in version 4.8.4 and yes, I tried to use header guards but this made no differences

Comment: unfortunately I don't understand the answer  which is linked by NathanOliver. So I somehow have to include those files in the building process but how do I do that. I use CMakeLists